# How to remove shadow in Music Player in my site?

Tags: html, css, element

I want to ask you, how to remove the big grey shadow in my [site](http://deilbeatz.com/) in 
**MUSIC PLAYER** block, in homepage? I tryed many things, but none worked to remove that. Can someone tell me how to remove or hide?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GCnt.png

Comment: i am seeing CSS over ridden lot of times,But for the issue you are facing remove margin-bottom from 
body.page-template-template-onepager-php #page-content .wpb_row {
    margin-bottom: -40px;
}

Comment: some of your container has got margin-bottom: -40px; change it to 0px;

Comment: oh let me see..

Comment: body.page-template-template-onepager-php #page-content .wpb_row -  not sure if the classes are dynamically changeable but check this selector in you code. I changed margin-bottom to 0 and everything seem to be ok now.

Comment: Thanks @web-developer

Comment: In the future I prefer you to right click on any wrong element on your site and click on the bottom of list 'INSPECT ELEMENT' or sth like that. You can then see highlighted element in DevToops and manipulate with css properties on live in order to see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following into your style.css file.

```
body.page-template-template-onepager-php #page-content .wpb_row {
margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: That not changed nothing.. See image in first post, what shadow i want to remove..

Answer (score 0):

```
body.page-template-template-onepager-php #page-content .wpb_row { margin-bottom: -40px; }
```

need to be

```
body.page-template-template-onepager-php #page-content .wpb_row { margin-bottom: 0px; }
```